# Why does the constructor function and instance of the constructor function have different prototypes?

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

I have a constructor function named `Duck`.

```js
function Duck(size, sound) {
  this.size = size;
  this.sound = sound;
}

let duck1 = new Duck(5, "quack");
console.log( Duck.prototype != duck1.prototye );
```

The prototype of `Duck` is not the same as the prototype of `duck1`. Doesn't it make sense for both to have same prototype?

Comment: they called "prototype" for a reason...

Comment: If duck1.prototype === undefined then how come Object.getPrototypeOf(duck1) returns Duck.prototype

Answer (score 1):

`duck1` does not *have* a prototype (It does have a `__proto__` internal property). `duck1.constructor` has a prototype and it is the same as `Duck.prototype`

```js
function Duck(size, sound) {
  this.size = size;
  this.sound = sound;
}
 let duck1 = new Duck(5, "quack");
 
 
 console.log(Duck.prototype);
 console.log(duck1.prototype);
 
 console.log(duck1.constructor.prototype === Duck.prototype);
 console.log(duck1.__proto__ === Duck.prototype); 
 console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(duck1) === Duck.prototype)
```

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf(duck1)` can be added for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Your `duck1` object has an internal `__proto__` property which is the same as `Duck.prototype`

You can read more [here](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/proto-vs-prototype-in-js-140b9b9c8cd5)

Answer (score 0):

Usually constructor function and instance of constructor function has the same prototype unless we changed the prototype of constructor function after creating the instance but let's not get into complexities here.

The constructor function prototype can be accessed using the *.prototype* property but objects (which do have a prototype) don't have prototype property. However, in browsers, we can use following to access prototype

```
objectInstance.__proto__;
```

This however isn't recommended. The standard way of accessing object's prototype is the following method:

```
Object.getPrototype(objectInstance);
```

as recommended by MDN

So, now if you try following, you will get true

```
console.log(Duck.prototype === duck1.__proto__); // true
```

or better

```
console.log(Duck.prototype === Object.getPrototype(duck1); // true
```